# How would I get 1 latest post from a query for 5 posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, query-posts

So I have a `wp_query` which is getting the 5 most recent posts from my Wordpress site. What I want to do is from within this query, grab the most recent post and show this as a sort of 'hero' post, and then take the other 4 posts (could be more than 4 if I change the query at a later date) and show in a list or grid below this hero post.

Here is my query code so far (obviously simplified):

```
<?php 

$query_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "5"
);

$listedPosts = new WP_Query($query_args);

// the loop

if ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
        $listedPosts->the_post();
        // loop content for hero post goes here (I need to get the most recent post).
    } 
}

// how would I show the other remaining posts in the query?

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`$current_post` property of `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties)

```
$query_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "5"
);

$listedPosts = new WP_Query($query_args);

// the loop

if ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
        $listedPosts->the_post();
        if ( (int) $listedPosts->current_post === 0 ) {
          // loop content for hero post
        } else {
          // loop content for remaining posts
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing your query args to something like below will order your posts  by modified date.

```
$query_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "5",
    "orderby" => "modified",
    "order" => "DESC"
);
```

You can then use a simple if else condition within the loop and print the first post as a hero and the remaining below it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `boolean` trigger will do the job.

```
<?php 

$query_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "5"
);

$listedPosts = new WP_Query($query_args);

// the loop

if ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
    $first_post = true;
    while ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
        $listedPosts->the_post();
        if( $first_post ) {
            $first_post = false;
            echo '<div class="post first">';
                // loop content for hero post goes here (I need to get the most recent post).
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="post">';
                // Rest of the posts.
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

Then use the `.post.first` class to style things differently. You can also load in different content, different order/classes on the content, different image sizes, etc.